# Convenience method to get sub-indices of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a convenient way to get say the first n number of indices from this array:

```
var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
```

and store it in another array, say `alphabet2 = ['a','b','c'];` without having to brute force with a loop? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the `slice` method](https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
> var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
> alphabet.slice(0,3)
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: @Roest I find the [w3schools javascript reference](http://w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp) to be great for that purpose.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Uh, **no thanks**. Try the [MDC JavaScript Reference](https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) as a better resource.

Comment: @pst While you might not find it useful, others certainly do. O am sure that those who maintain the w3schools website put a lot of effort  into it. If you find an error, you can contact them. What makes you dislike the site?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs http://w3fools.com/ When better sources are available, they should be used; the MDC JS Ref is better.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Personal distaste for w3schools aside, there is no reason I can think of to choose it as a reference over MDC in terms of quantity or quality .. thus I choose the *better* resource.

Comment: @pst Sometimes I find the mdn to have rather complex examples.